# Shell script file existence on Mac issue

Tags: macos, file, shell

Ok so I have written a .sh file in Linux Ubuntu and it works perfectly. However on a Mac it always returns that the file was not found even when it is in the same directory. Can anyone help me out?

.sh file:

```
if [ ! -f file-3*.jar ]; then
echo "[INFO] jar could not be found."
exit
fi
```

Just thought I'd add, this isn't for more than one file, it's for a file that is renamed to multiple endings.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `ls file-3*.jar`?

Comment: On Linux it outputs `file-302.jar` which is the current file name. Unfortunatly I don't have a Mac system which makes it more confusing for me.

Comment: So how do you know it doesn't work on Mac OS X ?

Comment: About 10 people who used the program on Mac OS X had the same error of the file not being found.

Comment: How are you invoking this script, exactly ?

Comment: If it is an error when the file is not found, you should do 2 things: print the message on stderr, and fail. `echo "[INFO] ... " >&2; exit 1;`

Comment: Read below your answer, I'm making it executable and running it in terminal.

Comment: Can you post the whole script (including shebang) and also the actual command line you use when you run it ?

Comment: Here is my script it's actually to compile scripts into a jar file :)

Comment: It shall run from cd ~/Documents/RSBot

Comment: A user using Mac OS X Lion has reported having the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment to @Paul R's answer, you said "The shell script is also in the same directory as the jar file. So they can just double click it after assigning SH files to open with terminal by default."  I suspect that's the problem -- when you run a shell script by double-clicking it, it runs with the working directory set to the user's home directory, not the directory where the script's located.  You can work around this by having the script cd to the directory it's in:

```
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
```

EDIT: $BASH_SOURCE is, of course, a bash extension not available in other shells.  If your script can't count on running in bash, use this instead:

```
case "$0" in
    */*)
        cd "$(dirname "$0")" ;;
    *)
        me="$(which "$0")"
        if [ -n "$me" ]; then
            cd "$(dirname "$me")"
        else
            echo "Can't locate script directory" >&2
            exit 1
        fi ;;
esac
```

BTW, the construct `[ ! -f file-3*.jar ]` makes me nervous, since it'll fail bizarrely if there's ever more than one matching file.  (I know, that's not supposed to happen; but things that aren't supposed to happen have any annoying tendency to happen anyway.)  I'd use this instead:

```
matchfiles=(file-3*.jar)
if [ ! -f "${matchfiles[0]}" ]; then
    ...
```

Again, if you can't count on bash extensions, here's an alternative that should work in any POSIX shell:

```
if [ ! -f "$(echo file-3*.jar)" ]; then
```

Note that this will fail (i.e. act as though the file didn't exist) if there's more than one match.

Comment: Hmm... if this works I'll let you know. Also, I didn't know BASH_SOURCE was available in sh?

Comment: Good point, I was assuming bash.  Finding the directory the script is in if much messier in a plain POSIX shell (and the matchfiles trick I showed won't work either).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies elsewhere, as the script works as expected on Mac OS X here:

```
$ if [ ! -f file-3*.jar ]; then echo "[INFO] jar could not be found."; fi
[INFO] jar could not be found.
$ touch file-302.jar
$ if [ ! -f file-3*.jar ]; then echo "[INFO] jar could not be found."; fi
$
```

Perhaps your script is being run under the wrong shell, or in the wrong working directory ?

Comment: It's #!/bin/sh and they are instructed to chmod +x the file. The shell script is also in the same directory as the jar file. So they can just double click it after assigning SH files to open with terminal by default.

Comment: Makes no sense to me at all :/

Comment: What about changing the shebang to #!/usr/bin/env sh

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it doesn't work for you, it doesn't work for your users? The default shell for OS X has changed over the years (see [this post](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005)) - but it looks like your comment says you have the `#!` in place.

Are you sure that your users have the JAR file in the right place? Perhaps it's not the script being wrong as much as it's telling you the correct answer - the required file is missing from where the script is being run.

Comment: Hmm... yes when I see your point, I try to help them, they insist that both files are in the same directory. Should I try converting it to BASH or something?

Comment: Output the path the script runs in, and see if it matches what the user thinks they did. Bonus points if you can walk to one of your users and watch them do it to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an answer, as a strategy: consider some serious logging. Echo messages such as `"[INFO] jar could not be found."` both to the screen and to a log file, then add extra logging, such as the values of `$PWD`, `$SHELL` and `$0` to the log. Then, when your customers/co-workers try to run the script and fail, they can email the log to you.

I would probably use something like

```
screenlog() {
    echo "$*"
    echo "$*" >> $LOGFILE
}

log() {
    echo "$*" >> $LOGFILE
}
```

Define `$LOGFILE` at the top of your script. Then pepper your script with statements like `screenlog "[INFO] jar could not be found."` or `log "\$PWD: $PWD"`.